# How to make xelatex invoke my manually installed ghostscript instead of the one accompanying TeXLive?

Tags: xetex, texlive, ghostscript

In my investigation, TeXLive installer will automatically install GhostScript (32 bit version) as follows.

[image]

I don't know whether `xelatex` depends on this GS.

I prefer to use GS that I manually install. So the question is

If `xelatex` invokes GS (I am not sure), how can I make `xelatex` invoke my manually installed GS rather than one installed by TeXLive?

In other words, if `xelatex` invokes `gswin32c`, how can I make it invoke `gswin64c` that I manually install?

Comment: I don't think XeLaTeX uses gs just in general, but you might be calling gs if you e.g. convert EPS figures or whatever. In general, you can ensure that your preferred version is used by ensuring that it occurs first in your `PATH` (or whatever the equivalent is on Windows). That is, unless the full path is explicitly specified somewhere, which would make it more difficult. I assume you could also customise the installation of TeX Live to avoid the installation of gs. (This must be a Windows thing - it isn't installed on GNU/Linux.)

Comment: Are you using TL 32bit because 64bit is not provided for Windows? (I half remember it being the case that only 32bit binaries were provided for Windows, in contrast to other platforms.)

Comment: Imho xelatex is reading the dvipdfmx.cfg and you can change the command there. I would suggest to make a copy in texmfhome and change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of `dvipdfmx.cfg`:

```
137 %% In TeX Live, we use the rungs wrapper instead of ps2pdf, becuse we
138 %% must omit the -dSAFER which ps2pdf specifies: in order for pstricks
139 %% to work with xetex,
140 %% /usr/local/texlive/*/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro (for
141 %% example) needs to be accessed.  (Also, it is better to use our
142 %% supplied gs on Windows.)  You can also add -dNOSAFER to the ps2pdf
143 %% command line.
144 %%
145 %% Incidentally, especially in TL, more than one dvipdfmx.cfg may be
146 %% extant.  You can find the one that is active by running:
147 %% kpsewhich -progname=dvipdfmx -format='other text files' dvipdfmx.cfg
148 %% and control which one is found by setting DVIPDFMXINPUTS.
149 %%
150 D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"
```

The `rungs` script is in the binary distribution of TeX Live; actually it is a symbolic link to `.../texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/rungs.tlu` (on windows it's probably `rungs.exe` that calls the same `rungs.tlu`); it has

```
if os.type == 'windows' then
   command={'gswin32c'}
else
   command={'gs'}
end
```

so the system will run whatever `gs` executable comes first after scanning the current `PATH`. On Windows running `gswin32c` is hardwired. You could try changing that line in `rungs.tlu`.